# Aligning icon font background in navigation, CSS

Tags: css

I am using an icon font for one of the list items in my main navigation.

I put this icon into it's own class, and gave it a font size so it matches the rest of the navigation. I also had to assign a specific line height for the icon font so it lines up.

Now the problem is when I hover over the icon (I am using a background colour), there is a gap underneath which is visible as you hover over it. This wouldn't be a problem if I wasn't using a background colour, but I would really like to keep this.

To illustrate what I mean, you can see the image here... https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94593656/test.jpg

Any ideas on how I can correct this, so that when you hover, there is no gap underneath?

I have uploaded the HTML and CSS here... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xeCLj

Comment: Please post your CSS and the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: Likely to be `vertical-align: middle` on the image that fixes this, but I won't post it as answer as we don't know the current CSS

Comment: ok here is the current html and css http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xeCLj - Can you view it in safari or chrome, I don't think the home icon is loading in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the iconfont class like so:

```
.iconfont {
  font-family: 'EntypoRegular';
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

With the padding and the line-height, this link becomes 40px high just like the navbar.  Height does not work on inline elements link anchors, so I used line-height instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if you actually tried it on the link, but vertical-align does not work for me ;(

Comment: It's not just the vertical-align, you also need to change the line-height too. See http://codepen.io/bwarner/full/uwlhB

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be kind of a hack : you set the property `min-height` to something like `20px`.